# ElementNotVisbleError (Cannot Click on Element)

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Salutations,

I'm writing code to scrape a website using Selenium and Excel VBA. The website in question has a menubar in which a menu option is visble to VBA only when hovered (class = "hovered" when the cursor is over the text, class = "" when the cursor is not over the text). Furthermore, while stepping into my code, I'm unable to click the link using Automation or Manually.

Please see code below:

```
WebsiteURL = "https://navinet.navimedix.com/signed-out/session-expired?
ReturnUrl=/"
driver.Get WebsiteURL
driver.Window.Maximize
driver.FindElementById("LoginPortletUsername").SendKeys (UserName) 'Reads 
Username
driver.FindElementById("LoginPortletPassword").SendKeys (Password) 'Reads 
password
driver.FindElementById("btnSignInSubmit").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))
driver.FindElementById("mh-workflows-my-health-plans-menu").Click
driver.FindElementById("workflows-menu-plan-aetna").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
driver.Window.Activate
driver.FindElementById("aetna-eligibility").Click
```

The code works up until point, however the following options to access the menupath do not work.

Option 1 (Move Cursor & Click)

```
SetCursorPos 2221, 289
Call SingleClick
```

With

```
Private Sub SingleClick()
SetCursorPos 2286, 69 'x and y position for Health Edge search
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub
```

And

```
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long 'mouse position
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long) 'user environment
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
```

Option 2 (Move Cursor & Find New Class)

```
SetCursorPos 2221, 289
driver.FindElementByClass("hovered").Click
```

Option 3 (Find Object Directly)

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='vertical-menu']/li[4]/ul/li/a").Click
```

Option 4 (Use Move To Element Via Menu Path & Click)

```
Set we = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='vertical-menu']/li[4]/ul/li/a") 
driver.Actions.MoveToElement(driver.FindElementById("aetna-eligibility")).MoveToElement(we).Click.Perform
```

Any tips or alternatives would help greatly. This has been driving me crazy!

Comment: I ended up taking the easy way out. I located the link to the menu option I attempted to click and just went straight there using "driver.get"                                           Link: <a href="/eligibility-benefits/aetna/search">Eligibility and Benefits Inquiry</a>